# Grails if exist else within config

Tags: grails, groovy

Some search results are being persisted to the view through config:

```
   Results:[
      [heading:'Id', property:'id'],
      [heading:'Title', property:'title'],
      [heading:'Status', property:'status?.value : "Awaiting value" '],
      [heading:'Timestamp', property:'timestamp']
    ]
```

The Status dose not work.
What i am after is so is status.value does not exist then show "Awaiting value"

I am not sure what is work with :

```
 status?.value : "Awaiting value"
```

It looks fine to me any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
  [heading:'Status', property:"${ status?.value ?: 'Awaiting value'}" ],
```

Comment: You can actually get rid of the question mark between status and value, everything should be handled by the elvis operator. Simply write status.value ?: 'Awaiting value'.

Comment: @lucke84 unless `status` is `null`